# Why I get "Expected field or method name at error"

Tags: android, proguard, build-error

Expected field or method name at ... -keepclassmembers class * { *** @null(android.view.View); }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved by removing `android:onClick="@null"` from one of my layout files.

Comment: I am getting this error : Expected field or method name at aapt_rules.txt 
keepclassmembers class * { *** @{listener::onClick}(android.view.View); }   Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I forgot to pass data binding event
`android:onClick="{}"`